# Feeding Tensorflow FIFOQueue multiple times

Tags: queue, deep-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to reset and re-feed a FIFIQueue in the middle of training. Is it possible?

I added a code to do this. This implementation is able to add new values to the training process but it cannot remove the old elements so I need to find a way to stop old queue runners. I tried `sess.run(qr.close_op)` and `sess.run(qr.cancel_op)` but did not work.

Also, I do not want to recreate the graph and reuse variables. `tf.train.string_input_producer` does not meet my need in the original implementation.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name="biases")
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
queue = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=50, dtypes=[tf.float32], shapes=[[]])
numbers = queue.dequeue()
batch_numbers = tf.train.batch([numbers], batch_size=20)
batch_numbers = tf.multiply(batch_numbers, 10.0) + biases # simulate a network operation
#Need to change the content of the queue 10 times
for k in range(10):

    input_numbers = [k*1.0 for i in range(100)]

    queue_op = queue.enqueue_many([input_numbers])

    qr = tf.train.queue_runner.QueueRunner(queue, [queue_op]*5)
    tf.train.queue_runner.add_queue_runner(qr)

    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for step in xrange(100):
        if coord.should_stop():
            break
        batch = sess.run([batch_numbers])
        print(batch)
    print("finished that batch")
```